# Error during the installation of SVM-light

Tags: linux, makefile, conda, verbosity, svmlight

I am trying to install `SVM-Light` on the cluster that I am working on but I got the following error:

```
svm_hideo.o:(.bss+0x38): multiple definition of `verbosity'; svm_common.o:(.bss+0x8): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:59: svm_learn_hideo] Error 1
```

The steps that I have done for the installation are the following (I followed this [tutorial](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/tj/svm_light/)):

```
wget https://download.joachims.org/svm_light/current/svm_light.tar.gz

gunzip -c svm_light.tar.gz | tar xvf -

ls
kernel.h     Makefile        svm_common.c  svm_hideo.c  svm_learn.h       svm_light.tar.gz
LICENSE.txt  svm_classify.c  svm_common.h  svm_learn.c  svm_learn_main.c  svm_loqo.c

 make
gcc -c  -O3                      svm_learn_main.c -o svm_learn_main.o
gcc -c  -O3                      svm_learn.c -o svm_learn.o
gcc -c  -O3                      svm_common.c -o svm_common.o
svm_common.c: In function ‘read_model’:
svm_common.c:600:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’ declared with attribute ‘warn_unused_result’ [-Wunused-result]
  600 |   fscanf(modelfl,"SVM-light Version %s\n",version_buffer);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
svm_common.c:605:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’ declared with attribute ‘warn_unused_result’ [-Wunused-result]
  605 |   fscanf(modelfl,"%ld%*[^\n]\n", &model->kernel_parm.kernel_type);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
svm_common.c:606:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’ declared with attribute ‘warn_unused_result’ [-Wunused-result]
  606 |   fscanf(modelfl,"%ld%*[^\n]\n", &model->kernel_parm.poly_degree);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
svm_common.c:607:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’ declared with attribute ‘warn_unused_result’ [-Wunused-result]
  607 |   fscanf(modelfl,"%lf%*[^\n]\n", &model->kernel_parm.rbf_gamma);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
svm_common.c:608:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’ declared with attribute ‘warn_unused_result’ [-Wunused-result]
  608 |   fscanf(modelfl,"%lf%*[^\n]\n", &model->kernel_parm.coef_lin);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
svm_common.c:609:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’ declared with attribute ‘warn_unused_result’ [-Wunused-result]
  609 |   fscanf(modelfl,"%lf%*[^\n]\n", &model->kernel_parm.coef_const);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
svm_common.c:610:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’ declared with attribute ‘warn_unused_result’ [-Wunused-result]
  610 |   fscanf(modelfl,"%[^#]%*[^\n]\n", model->kernel_parm.custom);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
svm_common.c:612:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’ declared with attribute ‘warn_unused_result’ [-Wunused-result]
  612 |   fscanf(modelfl,"%ld%*[^\n]\n", &model->totwords);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
svm_common.c:613:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’ declared with attribute ‘warn_unused_result’ [-Wunused-result]
  613 |   fscanf(modelfl,"%ld%*[^\n]\n", &model->totdoc);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
svm_common.c:614:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’ declared with attribute ‘warn_unused_result’ [-Wunused-result]
  614 |   fscanf(modelfl,"%ld%*[^\n]\n", &model->sv_num);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
svm_common.c:615:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’ declared with attribute ‘warn_unused_result’ [-Wunused-result]
  615 |   fscanf(modelfl,"%lf%*[^\n]\n", &model->b);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
svm_common.c:623:5: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fgets’ declared with attribute ‘warn_unused_result’ [-Wunused-result]
  623 |     fgets(line,(int)ll,modelfl);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
gcc -c  -O3                      svm_hideo.c -o svm_hideo.o
gcc  -O3                      svm_learn_main.o svm_learn.o svm_common.o svm_hideo.o -o svm_learn -L. -lm      
/mnt/netapp1/Optcesga_FT2_RHEL7/2020/gentoo/22072020/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.1.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: svm_hideo.o:(.bss+0x38): multiple definition of `verbosity'; svm_common.o:(.bss+0x8): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:59: svm_learn_hideo] Error 1
```

I have even tried to install it with `conda`, but without no success.

```
conda create myenv
conda activate myenv
conda install -c bioconda svmlight
conda list
# packages in environment:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main
_openmp_mutex             5.1                       1_gnu
libgcc-ng                 11.2.0               h1234567_1
libgomp                   11.2.0               h1234567_1
svmlight                  6.02                 hec16e2b_4    bioconda
```

But when I check if the package was installed sucessfully... it is not found.

```
python

Python 3.9.7 (default, Sep 16 2021, 13:09:58)
[GCC 7.5.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import svmlight
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /home/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/svmlight.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: PyCObject_Check
```

I also tried to install it using different ways:

```
conda install -c "bioconda/label/cf201901" svmlight
conda install -c bioconda svmlight 
pip install svmlight
pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade svmlight
```

But nothing...

Is there anybody who knows how to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The error is pretty clear: `svm_hideo.o:(.bss+0x38): multiple definition of 'verbosity'; svm_common.o:(.bss+0x8): first defined here`  So, there's a global variable or function named `verbosity` which is defined in BOTH the `svm_common.c` (or whatever extension) source file, AND the `svm_hideo.c` (or whatever extension) source file.  A given symbol can only be globally defined in one place (else which one should be used?)

Comment: @MadScientist Thanks for your reply. Yes, I know that both files have the same variable. I saw the error. The problem is that when I try to open the file, it is quite strange and I am not really sure what I should delete and I don't want to mess up the rest of the code. And the thing is that it is not something that I coded it myself... it could be an error from the latest update from the author or that I have something missing that I should install (but I don´t know what). For that reason I was just asking if someone could help me to fix it (or if someone has the same problem as me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

In order to install `svm-light`, it is necessary to install gcc 8.5.0 using the following code:

```
conda create myenv
conda activate myenv
conda install -c conda-forge gcc=8.5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Bioconda packages are built with [a very specific channel specification](https://bioconda.github.io/#usage), namely:

```yaml
# .condarc
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults
```

In order to properly use any Bioconda package, one must adhere to that channel specification. That is, the package should be installed like

```bash
## note that one can give packages to the `create` command
conda create -n myenv -c conda-forge -c bioconda svmlight
```

Also, note that there are two packages, `svmlight`, which is the compiled C++ library, and `pysvmlight`, which is a Python wrapper (only supports Python 2.7).